# Requires second refresh to see updated data

Tags: php, html, forms, refresh, page-refresh

I have an html file which contains a form. The HTML file includes a PHP file which fetches any data previously entered in the form from the database.

Whenever I update a column the same thing gets updated in the database, but requires a second refresh to show the updated data in the form.

The PHP code to fetch data is as below (data.php):

```
<?php
$obj=new Db;
$rslt=$obj->data($_SESSION['username']);
$dataid=$rslt[0][0];
?>
```

Included the above file using `<?php include 'data.php'; ?>`

The html file is as shown below (form.php):

```
<?php include 'data.php'; ?>
<form method="POST" action="process.php">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Data</label>
            <input list="dlist" name="datas" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $dataid; ?>">
                <datalist id="dlist">
```

After submitting the data we are using `header('Location:../form.php');` to get back to the html page.

I checked if the data is being updated in the database soon after the form is updated, and it was.

The data are being fetched correctly when we do a second reload. Before the second reload, it shows the same value as which was there before.

Any help is appreciated.

P.S. This issue only occurs occasionally for some browser.

Comment: maybe a stupid question, but do you actually call `exit;` after setting that location header? because if you happily output something else, the redirect may not happen at all.

Comment: The redirect is happening, and as I have said at last, I tried the same thing in different instances with different browser, and only few of them gave the same error.

Comment: don't try to be mean ... but add something at the end to your uri such as `header('Location: ../form.php?something');` and see if this is actually the url your landing on. Sending the form is a reload by itself, but there needs to happen another redirect ...

Comment: I am not trying to be mean, I am sorry if you felt so. And as you said, I am sending a message with the `header` if the update was successful, and the message is shown correctly mate.

Comment: I'm only insisting because it doesn't make any sense otherwise. except if you have some weird caches ...

Comment: I even tried after clearing my cache mate. As I said, it only occurs rarely. Just wanted to make sure my code works on everything. Also to let other future programmers know about this unusual occurring.